# quantifying ratios of infinite areas of differing sizes? e.g., in descending order: $x^2$ vs. $x$ vs. ln$x$ vs. cos$x$ vs $1/x$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals, infinity, geometric-measure-theory

In the case of two functions each with an antiderivative (indefinite integral) that increases forever without bound toward $+∞$ as $x$ approaches $+∞$ andor $-∞$, the area under each curve is infinite, i.e. some degree/magnitude/measure of $|∞|$. However, clearly they are not all equivalent. The negative_1st derivative with more modest end-behavior slopes intuitively and visually are smaller in scale than ones with more rapid end-behavior growth.

Would the ratio of one area under an integrable curve to another area under a different integrable curve simply be the former indefinite integral divided by the latter indefinite integral? Does this hold for non-infinite areas of integral curves as well, over finite and infinite domains? If so, then logically this should extend to less-finite integrals.

Comment: I don't think your approach is useful in studying function growth issues. For one thing, you presumably mean the rate of growth of the areas, unless you have some other means of quantifying different infinite areas, and now you're back to classifying/quantifying rates of growth of functions again. That said, you might be interested in Hardy's book [**Orders of Infinity**](https://archive.org/details/G_H_HARDY___ORDERS_OF_INFINITY), which incidentally is [fairly well known](https://www.google.com/search?q=hardy+%22orders+of+infinity%22) and thus a lot related to it can be found by googling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651